# Posting (by streaming?) with mikeal request

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, request

I'm trying to post a photo using mikeal request library, but the post comes emp

```
request = require('request')
fs = require("fs")
fs.createReadStream('zebra.jpg').pipe(request.post('http://localhost:2000'))
```

(on localhost:2000 I've got a simple echo for now)

Now, this works but I want to pass additional parameters using standard POST format.

What I'm actually trying to do is to post an image to Facebook via API, which means I'd like to include a title and possibly some more fields.

If streaming is not the right approach (although I see many benefits such as getting away without temporary files and buffers), what would be the right one?

Thanks for ideas.

UPD:

I've got this far:

```
fs.createReadStream('zebra.jpg').pipe(graph.post('418533674856800/photos', 
    {message:"I'm a new API photo!", name:"API Photo",privacy:{value:"EVERYONE"}},                  
                    function(err, res) {
                          console.log(res);
            }));
```

but it returns

```
dest.on('drain', ondrain);
   ^
TypeError: Object #<Graph> has no method 'on'
at [object Object].pipe (stream.js:52:8)
at Request._callback (c:\My Stuff\Creatiff\PRAGmatiki\Web-node.js\postaspage.js:66:36)
at Request.callback (c:\My Stuff\Creatiff\PRAGmatiki\Web-node.js\node_modules\request\main.js:119:22)
at Request.<anonymous> (native)
at Request.emit (events.js:70:17)
at Request.<anonymous> (c:\My Stuff\Creatiff\PRAGmatiki\Web-node.js\node_modules\request\main.js:521:16)
at Request.emit (events.js:67:17)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (c:\My Stuff\Creatiff\PRAGmatiki\Web-node.js\node_modules\request\main.js:483:14)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:88:20)
at HTTPParser.parserOnMessageComplete [as onMessageComplete] (http.js:130:23)
```

Is this happening because I'm streaming? Any help please!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var path = require('path'), 
    mime = require('mime');

request({
    url: 'http://localhost:2000',
    headers: {
        'content-type' : 'multipart/form-data'
    },
    method: 'POST',
    multipart: [{ 
        'Content-Disposition' : 'form-data; name="inputname"; filename="' + path.basename('zebra.jpg') + '"',
        'Content-Type' : mime.lookup('zebra.jpg'),
        body: fs.readFileSync('zebra.jpg')
    },{ 
        'Content-Disposition' : 'form-data; name="input[array]"; filename="' + path.basename('zebra1.jpg') + '"',
        'Content-Type' : mime.lookup('zebra1.jpg'),
        body: fs.readFileSync('zebra1.jpg')
    },{ 
        'Content-Disposition' : 'form-data; name="input[array]"; filename="' + path.basename('zebra2.jpg') + '"',
        'Content-Type' : mime.lookup('zebra2.jpg'),
        body: fs.readFileSync('zebra2.jpg')
    },{
        'Content-Disposition' : 'form-data; name="text"',
        body: "text input"                  
    }]
}, 
function(err, res, body){
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what `graph` is (doesn't appear in mikeael's documentation), but it doesn't implement the `Stream` interface so can't be used with `pipe()`.

To send multiple parts in a POST you need to use a request of type [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt). The latest version of [mikeal/request](https://github.com/mikeal/request/) has experimental support for this (with examples). Other modules also support it (needle for example, though stream support was a little lacking last time I looked).

Comment: Graph is Facebook Graph API
I don't understand the examples, should I call the file "field"?
Noodle seems to be something completely different, or am I getting it wrong? It says "A simple Oodle REST API wrapper for Node.JS" and oodle seems to be some kind of classified board.

Comment: oops I meant call the field "file" ;)

Comment: The example mentions neither "field" nor "file", so I don't know where you got that idea from.

Comment: I've found 'poster' module in the meantime that kind of does the job, but needle looks nice and I haven't seen it so thanks for pointing out :) Never mind the field thing, I think I'm getting there - thanks for the help